# JNLP and single sign on

Tags: java, cookies, single-sign-on, java-web-start, jnlp

Good morning,
I have web application that interacts with the user's machine via jnlp.
The problem I have is in a production environment where there is a component of Single Sign On.
The jnlp is download properly, it started, but when trying to invoke the url to download the jar I get an authentication error.
Is there a way to set in the url to download the jar the LTM coockie obtained during authentication phase?

Thank you